# using a function to renderUI(selectInput()) in Shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

Here's server.r

```
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$species <- renderUI({
     selectInput("species", 
                 label = "blah", 
                 choices = as.list(unique(iris$Species)))
      })
}
```

Then over in ui.r

```
ui <- fluidPage(
   fluidRow(        
       uiOutput("species")
)
```

This works as expected, a drop down select input appears like this:
[image]

Since I have multiple features I need to create a similar filter for in my actual data frame, I tried to do the same with a function:

In server.r

```
  outputFilters <- function(id, df) {
    output$id <- renderUI({
     selectInput(id, 
                 label = "blah", 
                 choices = as.list(unique(df$id)))
      })
  }

outputFilters("species", iris)
```

Then in ui.r same as before `uiOutput("species")`

However, now no drop down appears. Presumably my function is flawed. How can I use a function to generate the drop downs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that you could also do without a separate function in this case, by wrapping the desired ui component in `lapply`, or putting the `lapply` within the `uiOutput` to create all inputs at once, below is an example for the both two cases. Hope this helps!

```
ibrary(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  uiOutput('Species'),
  uiOutput('Sepal.Length'),
  h2('All inputs: '),
  uiOutput('my_inputs')
)


server <- function(input, output) {

  # Use lapply to create multiple uiOutputs.
  lapply(colnames(iris), function(x){
    output[[x]] <- renderUI({
      selectInput(paste0('input_',x), 
                  label = x, 
                  choices = as.list(unique(iris[['x']])))
    })
  })

  # Create all dropdown's at once.
  output$my_inputs <- renderUI({
    lapply(colnames(iris), function(x){
      selectInput(paste0('input_',x), 
                  label = x, 
                  choices = as.list(unique(iris)))
    })
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: This doesn't actually work when I tested it, the app is missing the creation of `df`

Comment: @zacdav, thanks for the heads up. That should be `iris`.

Comment: that makes it quite specific to iris, might be better to just adjust the function to take both name and data.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that each UI element needs its own `id` in the `output`

```
 outputFilters <- function(id, df) {
    output[[id]] <- renderUI({
     selectInput(id, 
                 label = "blah", 
                 choices = as.list(unique(df[[id]])))
      })
  }
```

now as long as `id` is a string in the function input it should generate the output element and you can refer with said `id`

You could then even use `lapply` to iterate over numerous, kind of how florian suggests.